# Recuperar ID do firebase em um ListView

Tags: android, firebase

Estou tentando recuperar o id do firebase no meu projeto de android. Estou começando a trabalhar com firebase agora e não sei muita coisa. É meio que diferente do Parde onde ele já me mostra o ID. Alguém sabe como faço para pegar o id do firebase ? No parse eu criava os campos e ele já me retornava o ID no firebase não conseguir recuperar.

Ele mostra a lista correto, mas quero pegar o id para passar para uma nova intent.

[image: Lista Firebase]

[image: Firebase no Android]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O Firebase não é um banco de dados relacional, portanto ele não possuí um "id" que é necessário para fazer os relacionamentos.

Sendo um banco de dados NoSQL (Não relacional) do tipo [Documental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) seu identificador é a "key", no caso `item1` por exemplo.

Um banco de dados documental deve conter todos os dados necessários para o seu funcionamento, não seria então, necessário uma ID pois esse campo não seria referenciado por nada.

No exemplo abaixo:

```
"lutadores": {
    "blanka": {
        "magia":"Electric Thunder"
    },
    "ryu": {
        "magia":"Hadouken"
    },
    "sagat": {
        "magia":"Tiger Uppercut"
    }
}
```

Ao requisitar ao Firebase o Json lutadores, terei o seguinte JSON:

```
{"blanka":{"magia":"Rolling Attack"},"ryu":{"magia":"Hadouken"},"sagat":{"magia":"Tiger Uppercut"}}
```

Caso queira um objeto específico, posso requisitar o objeto passando sua key:
`/lutadores/blanka.json` retornará : 
`{"magia":"Rolling Attack"}`

Estes exemplos foram retirados do [CDG Pato Branco](http://gdgpatobranco.org/2015/04/21/firebase-introduction/), tem uns exemplos bem legais lá.

Neste [link](http://www.itexto.net/devkico/?p=1199) tem um comparativo sobre os tipos de bancos NoSQL e suas vantagens/desvantagens.